# Possible to manage linux services from website?

Tags: php, shell, scripting, html

I have a couple services that id like to have access to from a website. Like maybe a simple website with login for users and access to start|Stop|Restart services if they are down.
IDK if this is possible within a webpage as im not all that experienced yet.

From a shell i can just type out **service b3-2 start** and the service will start. now i just want to be able todo that from within a webpage where the start|Stop|Restart are buttons and there's a info/status area and an output box below everything to show errors if any.

If anyone can help me with this that would be awesome. Mostly my questions are-

- Is it possible to do this from a webpage?
- If so how hard will it be to create?
- What else can you tell me to better help me with this?

*on a side note il be using this for mostly only my B3 services(Big Brother Bot).*

Comment: I wouldn't per se put this under the PHP tag. I suspect there probably is somewhere some kind of package you can install that creates such a website (however, I didn't find any in the first search results and I don't have time to look further).

Comment: You could check out [webmin](http://www.webmin.com), although that might be a little overkill for your project.

Comment: i agree with styxxy, im hoping there is already a web interface that i can just mod or it works right out of the box. but i will attempt to create my own if need be.

Comment: Webmin would probably do this for you, but its overkill for just a few services. http://www.webmin.com/standard.html  You might have better luck on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote long time ago an 'Eggdrop Webinterface' in PHP with http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php Module.

You can connect with this module via SSH to your linux server and submit shell commands. In my Webinterface I wrote an Shellscript that do all the jobs (Add / remove / start / stop and so on) and executed over php ssh2 module.

```
<?php
class ssh
{
private $sql;
private $con;

private static $instance;

public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!self::$instance)
    {
        self::$instance = new ssh();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

function __construct()
{
    $this->sql = sql::getInstance(); 
}

/* Verbindung über SSH aufnehmen */
public function connect ($rootid)
{
    global $cfg;

    $q = $this->sql->query("SELECT ROOT_SSH_IP, ROOT_SSH_USER, ROOT_SSH_PASS, ROOT_SSH_PORT FROM ".prfx."rootserver WHERE ROOT_ID = '".$rootid."'");

    $r = $this->sql->content($q);

    $blowfish = new Blowfish($cfg["BLOWFISHKEY"]);

    $pass = $blowfish->Decrypt($r["ROOT_SSH_PASS"]);

    $this->ssh_connect($r["ROOT_SSH_IP"], $r["ROOT_SSH_PORT"], $pass, $r["ROOT_SSH_USER"]);

    return true;

}

/* Disconnect */
public function my_ssh_disconnect($reason, $message, $language) {
    printf("Server disconnected with reason code [%d] and message: %s\n",
    $reason, $message);

    return true;
}

/* Eigentliche ssh_connect Funktion */
public function ssh_connect($host, $port, $pass, $user="root")
{
    $methods = array(
      'kex' => 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1',
      'client_to_server' => array(
        'crypt' => '3des-cbc',
        'comp' => 'none'),
      'server_to_client' => array(
        'crypt' => 'aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc',
        'comp' => 'none'));

    $callbacks = array();

    $this->con = ssh2_connect($host, $port, $methods, $callbacks);
    if (!$this->con) die('Connection failed');
    else {

        if (!ssh2_auth_password($this->con, $user, trim($pass))) {
            die("login failed.");
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/* Befehle ausführen */
public function ssh_exec ($cmd, $stderr=true)
{
    if ($stderr == true)
    {
        $stream = ssh2_exec($this->con, $cmd);

        $err_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

        stream_set_blocking($err_stream, true);
        $result_err = stream_get_contents($err_stream);

        if (empty($result_err))
        {
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

            $out = stream_get_contents($stream);

            return $out;
        }
        else {
            return $result_err;
        }
    }
    else {

        $stream = ssh2_exec($this->con, $cmd);

        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

        $out = stream_get_contents($stream);

        return $out;
    }
}

/* Verbindung beenden */
public function quit()
{
    $stream = ssh2_exec($this->con, 'exit');
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $output = stream_get_contents($stream);

    return true;                
}
```

}

In my case I stored Serveraccounts in MySQL Table with encrypted password.

hope that little class helps

Comment: thx for the script, i will look into this further wen i get home.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to "write it yourself" you could mix bash,php and/or other scripting..

Comment: a simple webpage is all i need really. i can just password protect the directory from within cpanel. i just need a webpage that can control this service without breaking the bank or being to complicated to replicate.